Change the shape of a face
So I have this cylinder that I want it to have an entry on both sides, but i want to make it rectangular, not this rounded shape. How do i make it?

If i fill it, it makes it round. I want it to fill till the vertices, you know? I want all the 4 faces (top, bottom, left and right) to fill everything and the face on the "outside".


Show us your modifier stack. You probably have misplaced *Edge Split * node, order incorrect modifier order

You seem to have a "subdivision" modifier, and that's what rounds edges.
The same way you created edge creases to keep the sharp top and bottom edges, you need to create edge creases around these new faces you are creating.
Later, you will need to remove these floating vertices and edges that don't have faces. And you will need to merge duplications because you have dettached faces there. (Select all a, and merge m by distance)
